# Where in Quran Allah mentions that Hazrat Ismail was the ancestor of Hazrat Muhammad PBUH?

Tags: quran

Where in Quran Allah mentions that Hazrat Ismail was the ancestor of Hazrat Muhammad PBUH? Is it mentioned there? Or we got this information from Hadith only?